# bunch of RSS to blog?

Tags: rss

Is there a ready available service that turns a bunch of RSS feeds into a blog like tumblr or posterous?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the feeds in Google Reader, give them a common label and in the settings make the label public. This will create a public URL to a web page with the latest entries.

The page is a simple display, without features like commenting.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a load of RSS feeds into a blog-like display, you could try [Yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/). Popular services like Blogger and [Tumblr](http://www.widgetslab.com/2007/11/07/tumblr-widget-and-instant-content/) have javascript widgets too. Then there's [Feedburner](http://www.consumingexperience.com/2008/06/feeds-basics-101-using-feedburner-why.html).